# App Store blocks socket.io in react native apps during review?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, mobile, applescript

I am making an app in React Native and I want to use the Socket.io api to communicate in real time with the back-end. I wonder if this lib is blocked in the App Store review.

Comment: I am also using socket.io in my app but I did not face any issue while uploading it to the play store.

Comment: What makes you think they would block it ? And how ?